# Why isn't the shipped ldap functionality work in TorQ?

Tags: kdb, torq

I have 2 kdb apps:

1. a TorQ plant for a personal project
2. some other company app that runs in dev and prod

I want to use LDAP to authenticate myself in the TorQ app.

I have configured it with the correct server and port (I took the configs from the other app), but I am missing some parameters.

One parameter missing is the 'domain'
The other parameter missing is 'bind'

I cannot see what's in the .ldap.authenticate function.

Does anyone know how this can be debugged ? Should I think about replacing the LDAP utility altogether ?

Comment: Have a look at [LDAP interface for kdb+](https://github.com/KxSystems/ldap) from KX, might work instead.